# What to put in down() function if up() drops table?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-migrations

Just starting to learn Laravel, so go easy. I made a couple migration files to try out.  The first creates a table, the second adds a column, and the third drops the table.  I'm curious to know what I should put in the `down()` function of the third migration, since you can't "undrop" a table.  How do you handle rolling back a migration that drops a table?

Answer (score 2):

The point of the down function is to restore the database to the same state it was in before you ran the up function. So if `up()` drops a table, then `down()` should recreate that table.

It is important to note that you probably will lose data if you do this. But migrations are intended to manage the **scheme** of the database, not the **contents**. If you want to preserve the data, that's a **backup**.